# Using google custom search API to find images

Tags: google-custom-search, google-ajax-api

I want to use Google's Custom Search API to find images using GET request. Like described [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest). But I don't want to look on images on one specific site, but want to get results like [this](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=some+request&espv=2&biw=1677&bih=932&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVovWBkajKAhXBaRQKHc2GDjMQ_AUIBigB). How I can do this with the Custom Search API?

Sending this request returns nothing:
`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[MY_KEY]&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=some+request&&safe=off&searchType=image&fileType=png`. This `cx` is from [google's manual](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest)

I must set `cx` param, but this value links my request to site, specified in [cse control panel](https://cse.google.com/all). However I don't want to limit my results to one site.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here:
[Google Custom Search > Overview](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview)

> Google Custom Search enables you to create a search engine for your website, your blog, or a collection of websites.

It doesn't sound like that is what you are trying to do (you don't seem to want to search a predefined subset of resources).

Comment: While digging the internet i found that [Ajax Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/) is exactly what I need (am I right?), but it is deprecated and google recommends me to use Custom Search API.

Ok, if it not what I need, are there other API to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware the question is over 6 years old, but better late than never. It's possible to create a Google programmable search engine that can search the entire web for images. When you create a programmable search engine, there is an option to search the entire web instead of just web sites that you specify. See https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/about/.

As an alternative, you could try [Bing Image Search API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/apis/bing-image-search-api). There is a limit to the number of image searches you can submit per day for free, but I have rarely hit the limit.